# issue with accessing Resource file in View

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, c#-4.0

i have created a separate project for resources file, and a separate for my asp.net mvc3 application.

for every single label i am trying to get the text from the resource file for that i have added the below namespace in the web.config file so that my resource file will be available for the View.

```
    <pages>
  <namespaces>
    <add namespace="System.Web.Helpers" />
    <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc" />
    <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Ajax" />
    <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Html" />
    <add namespace="System.Web.Routing" />
    <add namespace="System.Web.WebPages"/>
    <add namespace="Project.Resources"/>
  </namespaces>
</pages>
```

but still the recources are not available to my view

please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the namespace in the sub web.config file as well

[image: this is the other web.config file]

Comment: hi thanks for ur reply but i am using .aspx engine instead of razor engine